# golang gin one route for different queries

Tags: go, go-gin

is it possible in gin to have one route with either `:item` (name)  OR `:id`?

example:

```
r.GET("/inventories/(:item|:id)", controllers.FindInventory)
```

Then I could probably do something like ...

```
func FindInventory(g *gin.Context) {
    var inv models.Inventory

    if item:
       err := models.DB.Where("item = ?", g.Param("item")).First(&inv).Error
    else:
       err := models.DB.Where("id = ?", g.Param("id")).First(&inv).Error
       
    if err != nil {
        g.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Record not found!"})
        return
    }

    g.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": inv})
}
```

or is there a way to use one route for two types of queries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported. But there must be some way to distinguish between an item and an id. So it's easy to implement the logic yourself.

Like this:

```golang
r.GET("/inventories/:item", controllers.FindInventory)
```

```golang
func FindInventory(g *gin.Context) {
    var inv models.Inventory

    item := g.Param("item")
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(item)
    if err != nil {
        err := models.DB.Where("item = ?", item).First(&inv).Error
    } else {
        err := models.DB.Where("id = ?", id).First(&inv).Error
    }
    if err != nil {
        g.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Record not found!"})
        return
    }

    g.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": inv})
}
```

But if it's not possible to distinguish, then you'd need to have two separate request paths like

- `/inventories/by-item/:item`
- and `/inventories/by-id/:id`

**Update on 2023-05-31**: merged @EpicAdidash's and @boyvinall's comments into the answer. Thank you!

Comment: this is only possible in certain requests

Comment: Yes, but there should be some way to distinguish between item and id.

Comment: and, if it's not possible to distinguish, then you'd need to have two separate request paths like `/inventories/by-item/:item` and `/inventories/by-id/:id`

Comment: @boyvinall and EpicAdidash, I have merged your comments into the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with params but the first thing is that data of item and id should be different otherwise you have to resort to queries to do that